# How do I properly assign memory to an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, memory, malloc

Sorry if this is such a novice question, this is my first time on this site!

Currently, I have an array:

```
float delayTable[];
```

This is for an audio programming class, so this array will be used to store individual audio samples. In one second, it needs to store 44,100 different floats. How can I use malloc to give it enough memory to hold 10+ seconds of data? Cheers!

Comment: Floats! sorry for confusion.

Comment: If you know it's exactly 44,100 elements then you don't need `malloc`. Just declare `float delayTable[44100]`. You may be better off allocating the array in the data-section rather than the stack. For that purpose, declare it as `static` in the function, or as global in the file.

Comment: It will store 44,100 floats, not integers. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Well, I wanted to allocate enough data for 10 seconds of audio. So I did:

    float delayTable[441000];

But it gave me a bus 10 error

Comment: Furthermore, I believe that you can define a `typedef` equal to "`float[44100]`" and then take the `sizeof()` that `typedef.`  (Or, "X times that amount.")  Then use `malloc()` to get that number of bytes from the heap. I think ...

Comment: You got a bus error more than likely because a float array of that size may have blown your static.  You malloc or make it global instead.

Comment: Since you say this is your first question, a bit of nitpicking on the question format: don't say things like "this is my first question" :P Think of this like a big giant community-edited FAQ. People with the same question in the future gain nothing from all the "cheers" and "thanks in advance". It'll just be noise for them.

Comment: Michael: Would using malloc 'bypass' the issue of blowing the static memory allocation?
Part of my problem is that I am building a program that is nested inside of someone else's program. I will freely admit that I don't quite understand its inner workings, I am just creating my own set of code inside of it.

Comment: Please get yourself a C book. That's a much better way to learn C syntax than asking questions like this and getting answers you don't understand yet.

Comment: You can't `malloc` space for a variable of array type. Your options are: (a) allocate the array without using malloc, (b) use a pointer to access malloc'd space

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by 10+ seconds, that would be potentially any number higher than 10...
If you want to allocate an array for 10 seconds of the signal, you have to multiply the sample rate by time, and multiply that by the size of the sample, so:

```
float *delayTable = malloc(44100 * 10 * sizeof(float));
```

Alternatively:

```
float *delayTable = malloc(44100 * 10 * sizeof(*delayTable));
```

Comment: Are you using a different name for the array in this? The malloc portion of the code makes sense, but I don't see where it is actually putting that number into "delayTable"

Answer (score 1):

The question asked for "10+" seconds recording time - suggesting the length is not fixed. This answer is for "0+" seconds recording time, expanding the array as the recording proceeds.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float getsample(void) {                         // placeholder function
    return (float)rand()-1;
}

int main(void) {
    float *delayTable = NULL;                   // start with no array memory
    float sample;
    int samplespersec = 44100;
    int secs = 0;
    int numsamples = 0;
    int maxsamples = 0;

    while ((sample = getsample()) >= 0) {       // imaginary, func returns < 0 when done
        if (numsamples == maxsamples) {         // array is full
            secs++;                             // memory for one more second
            maxsamples = secs * samplespersec;  // improve by checking int constraint
            delayTable = realloc(delayTable, maxsamples * sizeof(*delayTable)); // expand
            if (delayTable == NULL)
                exit(1);                        // improve this error condition
        }
        delayTable[numsamples++] = sample;
    }
    printf("Recorded %d samples\n", numsamples);
    //free(delayTable);
    return 0;
}
```